# How to apply padding on the Decimal Values in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, padding

I need help on applying padding on the Decimal values in Oracle.

E.g.:

- `-36693.76` should be displayed as `-000036693.76`
- `367.2` should be displayed     as `+000000367.20`

Padding should be (9,2) and sign also should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB) with the appropriate format mask:

```
TO_CHAR(the_column,'S000000000.00')
```

The `S` indicates the position of the sign. The `0` indicates to display a `0` if no value is available for that digit (a `9` would display a blank)

The following:

```sql
with sample_data(the_column) as (
  select 367.2 from dual 
  union all
  select -36693.76 from dual
  union all
  select 1.234 from dual
  union all
  select 1.236 from dual
)
select TO_CHAR(the_column,'S000000000.00') as the_column
from sample_data;
```

returns:

```
THE_COLUMN   
-------------
+000000367.20
-000036693.76
+000000001.23
+000000001.24
```

Note how `1.234` got rounded to `1.23` and `1.236` to `1.24`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
with cte(num) AS(
  select 367.2 from dual 
  union all
  select -36693.76 from dual
)
select case when num < 0 then  concat('-', TO_CHAR(num*-1,'000000000.00'))  else concat('+', TO_CHAR(num,'000000000.00')) end 
from cte
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe a bit cumbersome solution.